# What are the limitations of Dynamic Language Runtime in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I know that anonymous functions are not supported as arguments to a dynamic method call. What are other such limitations of DLR in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* use anonymous functions, you just have to cast them first:

```
dynamic list = new List<string>() { "10", "20" };
dynamic converted = list.ConvertAll((Func<string, int>) (x => int.Parse(x)));
```

The same is true of method group conversions:

```
foo.Click += (EventHandler) MyClickHandler;
```

Other restrictions I've encountered so far:

- Static methods and constructors can't be dynamic in terms of the type, but *can* be dynamic in terms of the arguments
- You can't use `dynamic` in a type constraint
- You can't use `dynamic` as a type argument in an interface for a class declaration, but you *can* use it as a type argument for a base class, i.e.

  ```
  class Invalid : IEnumerable<dynamic>
  class Valid : List<dynamic>
  ```
- Extension methods aren't discoverable at execution time (but you can call the static method directly with dynamic arguments)
- There's a bug in 4.0b1 such that you can't convert from `dynamic[]` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` - that will be fixed for the release.
- You can't use `dynamic` as a base class

(Note that these are limitations of C# 4.0 as much as of the DLR itself. I got the impression that was what you meant though.)

Comment: Don't all uses of delegates need the cast, not just anons/lambdas? e.g. in btn.Click += MyClickHandler; if btn is dynamic but does have a Click event, that won't work. You need the cast around the MyClickHandler method name.

Comment: @Earwicker: Not *all* uses of delegates, but you're right that method group conversions require a cast as well. Will update my answer accordingly.